# How to run code from sql file directly from toad oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

i have a *.sql file on my desktop. How can i create a job in toad for oracle so that it can directly pick up the file and run it everyday at a specific time. 
thank you

Comment: any answers or opinions..

Answer (score 1):

What version of Toad? If it's a somewhat newer one, check out the Automation Designer. It's available from the Utilities menu.

1. Create a new app on the left side, give it a meaningful name
2. On the DB Misc tab double click the Execute Script action to add it to your app.
3. Double click the new execute script action and add your file to it. Set other options within as desired.
4. Click Apply and exit the script action properties dialog.
5. Right click on your script action and choose Schedule. Work through the Windows Task Scheduler prompts and it will be setup for you.

Answer (score 0):

well different version of the  TOAD have different options 
the best way i would suggest you is - on the button "Execute as script"

```
Execute as script --> Execute via SQL plus
```

then the SQL-plus window will pop up and it will auto connect to your DB. 
Gather all your sql queries / script in the file and run below command

```
@C:\Users\Desktop\script.sql
```

this will start executing the script from file directly and will give the log in the SQL plus window.